# Recursion in Python without using a local/internal variable

Tags: python, recursion

For the sake of space and avoiding confusion I'm not going to post my exact problem, but a similar one instead. I want to, in Python, print a sequence of numbers backwards. The restraints are that I must use recursion, and I must not have any local variables inside of my function. For example, if given the number 8 for the function below, I would want it to print 1,2,4,8. Also assume that the input is an even integer, please.

```
def function(x)
     if(x!=1)
          x = x/2
```

I've racked my brains for a while now, but I can't seem to find anything that will actually print the last value (i.e. here I can only get it to produce 1,2,4). Here are my thoughts so far:

```
def function(x)        
     if(x!=1)
          x = x/2
     function(x)
     print x,
```

The above code prints 1,2,4, given that x is initially 8. Yet, if I place the recursive call anywhere in front of the "x = x/2" line, the value of x will constantly stay at 8.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do? I'm sure there's something simple I'm overlooking, but I do not know what it is.

EDIT: Whoops, forgot to put my print statement in there.

EDIT 2: Many thanks to both of you! Can't believe it was as obvious as putting the calculations themselves into the function calls to avoid reassigning the variable each time.

Again, thank you much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is fine, but you do not actually print anything. How about

```
def function(x):
    if(x != 1):
        function(x / 2)
    print x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(x):
    if(x>1):
        func(x/2)
    print x

func(8)
```